# Why task scheduler is not running powershell script in clearcase dynamic view [network share ]when the machine is locked?

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, clearcase

I am using windows 2008 R2 64 bit Operating system. I have clearcase dynamic view. [You can think of it as a network mapped drive]

When scheduling basic task with the option "Run whether the user is logged on or not" , my powershell script is not executing.

It says operation executed successfully but nothing has been done. Our build will send mail at the end I did not receive any mail.

Answer (score 0):

> You can think of it as a network mapped drive

Not exactly: this is a MVFS mounting point.

Make sure you are:

- using the full and complete path of a dynamic view: `M:\myView\myVob\...`
- executing your script in a vob (`M:\myView\myVob` or below) and not in the view (`M:\myView`)